# Failed to run inner join to fetch data (from a Microsoft Server) using RStudio SQL tool (w/ good db connection)

Tags: sql, r, inner-join

Here is my problem: I'm using R-SQL tool to fecth data from a server. Although my db connection is good, and I can run query against each individual table, I couldn't run inner join of two tables using the same R-SQL tool, ie., dbconnent (from DBI) and sqlQuery(from RODCB)

- Here is the error message when running dbconnent(): "Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. "

Here are abbreviated codes

```
 ----
 sql1 <- "
  SELECT 
    e.RID, e.Form, 
    i.ItemName, i.Response
  FROM ExamResult AS e 
    INNER JOIN ItemResult AS i 
    ON e.RID=i.RID
  WHERE  e.ExamSeriesCode= 'Exam1'
" 

 result <- dbGetQuery(conn, sql1)
```

Thank you!

- To debug, I ran query against each individual table, it went fine.
- I checked the linking var (RID" in each table, they have identical name and property.
- I tried both dbconnent (from DBI) and sqlQuery(from RODCB). the same problem ( not running inner join) persists.

Comment: The error references a column named "Key", but your sample data does not have that. Is there something else in your query that you're simplifying for this question? If you do have a "Key" in the real query, then `Key` is a reserved word; bracket it as `[Key]` and it should fix the error.

Comment: You are genius! -- I do have a var "Key" in the query, Bracketing as [Key] is the solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message includes a reference to `Key`,

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'. [Microsoft][ODBC 
Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

This suggests your real query has `Key` in it. This is a reserved word in SQL, requiring that it be escaped. Most DBMSes do this by using brackets around the reserved word to clearly identify it as a SQL Identifier (as opposed to a Literal, such as the string *value* `'hello'`).

Bottom line, in your real query, replace `Key` with `[Key]` (or `"Key"`).

To do this programmatically (and confirm that in fact brackets work with your specific DBMS), you can use:

```r
DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, "Key")
# <SQL> "Key"
```

which doesn't seem to tell you much, but the double quotes are real.

```r
as.character(DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, "Key"))
# [1] "\"Key\""
```

Many (including SQL Server) will accept both `[Key]` and `"Key"` without ambiguity.

Comment: You're very observant! Thank you so much for your kindest help --I will never forget this, lol